# How does Android Studio determine the module when running instrumentation tests?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

In Android Studio when I click the play button to run a test it creates a "Run/Debug" configuration. In doing so it automatically selects a module. If you click "Edit Configuration" you can see what it selected.

**How does Android Studio determine what module to select?**

I have tested with two different multi module projects. In one of them it selects the *correct* module (the module where the test resides). In the other one it always selects the app module.

I want it to always select the module where the test resides but can't find where to change this or why it's selecting the app module in that one project. The reason is because when I run the test from Gradle tasks it fails since it can't find the test in the app module (because it's not in the app module).

In both projects the package name of the app module and the module that contains the test are completely different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**How does Android Studio determine what module to select?**

By default, android studio selects the `Application` module. The first time you start Android studio (creating a project, importing a project, opening a project), android studio selects the `Application` module (normally this is named as **app**) This is for the `Android App` configuration.

By default, there are no `Android JUnit` or `Android Instrumented Tests` configuration enabled. This is created when you run any tests in any module.

**Setting default Module for any Configuration**

This is easy. As shown in below image, just select the Configuration under **Defaults** and set the Module. This will be the default module, every time you create new configuration. That said, I don't usually do this. When you want to run the tests of a module, just right click the **tests** package of that module and run the test. This will create a Configuration for you. Then you can always select that configuration when you want to run the tests.

[image]

Comment: actually I found this out as well and it works. I hadn't updated the question yet since the Gradle tasks still were not working. But it's a long story and I think I've now ruled it out as being related to this so this is the correct answer for this specific question. Thanks for answering.